# Conflicto con el procedimiento Read al manipular ficheros .dat en Firemonkey

Tags: pascal

Tengo un problema a la hora de manipular fichero .dat en el programa que estoy haciendo.
Crear el fichero y guardar información en él no me da problemas.
El problema surge cuando intento leerlo y extraer la información porque me entra en conflicto el procedimiento Read con una función de igual nombre que el valor que devuelve es de tipo numérico (integer):

```
read(_handle:Integer; _buf:Pointer; _len:Cardinal):Integer
```

Todo parece indicar que es algún componente que estoy usando que tiene esa función implícita... Por lo que me gustaría saber algún tip que me indique qué componente o qué Unit utiliza la función antes mencionada o cualquier otra, con el objetivo de hallar un solución, ya sea sutituyendo el componente o utilizando otra alternativa que no me entre en conflicto con lo que quiero hacer.

Código que utilizo para manipular los ficheros .dat:

```
type
  TMainForm = class(TForm)
  ...
end;

type
  TMiFichero = record
     1,
     2,
     3,
     4: String[100]  
 end;
```

Después en Guardar_button.click
declaro:

```
var 
  Opciones: TMiFichero;
  F: file of TMiFichero;
begin
  if (1.Text<>'') and (2.Text<>'') and (3.Text<>'') and (4.Text<>'') then begin
  Opciones.1:=1.Text;
  Opciones.2:=2.Text;
  Opciones.3:=3.Text;
  Opciones.4:=4.Text;
  AssignFile( F, ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'mifichero.dat');
  Rewrite(F);
  Write(F, Opciones);
  CloseFile(F);
 end
 else
  ...
end;
```

Todo bien hasta ahí...

En el botón `Leer_button.click`
declaro:

```
var
  Opciones: TMiFichero;
  F: file of TMiFichero;
begin
    // Pregunto si existe el fichero
    if exist(GetCurrentDir+'mifichero.dat') then
    begin
       AssignFile( F, ExtractFilePath( ParamStr(0)) + 'mifichero.dat' );
       Reset(F);
       Read(F,Opciones);   <--- Aquí es donde me da el problema
       CloseFile( F );
       1.text:= Opciones.1;
       2.Text:= Opciones.2;
       3.Text:= Opciones.3;
       4.Text:= Opciones.4;`
```

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español.
Para evitar los conflictos de este tipo, basta con que añadas delante del nombre de la función, la unit que la contiene, de esta forma evitas que el compilador "dude" o escoja la incorrecta.

En este caso añade la unit `System` a la llamada de la función `Read` (ver la documentación de la función).

```
   AssignFile( F, ExtractFilePath( ParamStr(0)) + 'mifichero.dat' );
   Reset(F);
   System.Read(F,Opciones); 
   CloseFile( F );
```

Es posible que puedas evitar la selección incorrecta de la función `Read`, modificando el orden de los `USES` que tienes en esa unit, pero es una solución menos segura.